# How subscribe only to future updates of BehaviorSubject?

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I want to subscribe only to future update of a BehaviorSubject, I did it with this approach, but i think this is not a good one.

```
BehaviorSubject<Account> behaviorSubject = BehaviorSubject.create();

PublishSubject<Account> publishSubject = PublishSubject.create();

behaviorSubject.subscribe(publishSubject);

behaviorSubject.onNext(new Account()); 

behaviorSubject.subscribe(result -> Log.e("print1", result.toString()));

publishSubject.subscribe(result -> Log.e("print2", result.toString()));

behaviorSubject.onNext(new Account());
```

Regards.

Comment: This is totally fine. If your `BehaviorSubject` has an initial value, you can use `behaviorSubject.skip(1).subscribe(...)` as well.

Comment: Thanks I wasn't sure if I was doing well.